# How to remove a program through Powershell?

Tags: function, powershell, scripting

I want to create a function to remove a program through powershell. What I can't seem to figure out is how exactly to do that.

My code:

```
function RemoveProgram {
    $app = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {
        $_.Name -match $args
    }
    $app.Uninstall()
}
```

However, when I run this, I get

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance] does not contain a method named 'Uninstall'.
```

Does anyone have some tips on how to make it better?

Comment: the CIM cmdlets _do not_ have a live connection to the data. it is by design. you need to invoke the method with `Invoke-CimMethod` OR switch back to using `Get-WmiObject` since it still has live connections to the data.

Comment: Get-WmIObject doesn't work on my version of powershell

Comment: ah! then you likely otta put that info - and your PoSh version - in your Question. it is important ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was actually able to find a way to do this without creating my own function. I used a module called `ProgramManagement`. https://github.com/pldmgg/ProgramManagement

Hope this helps and thanks to anyone who tried to help me solve this!

Answer (score 1):

This code will work. It may take while to run though.

```bsh
param(
    [string] $programToUninstall = "BlueJeans"    
)

function RemoveProgram([string] $program) {
    Invoke-CimMethod `
        -Query ('select * from Win32_Product where name like "%' + $program + '%"') `
        -MethodName "Uninstall" 
}

RemoveProgram -program $programToUninstall
```

Comment: You can also pipe get-ciminstance to invoke-cimmethod.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell 5 and msi installs only.  Win32_Product is msi only as well, and verifies every msi when it runs, which is why it's so slow.

```
function RemoveProgram {
  get-package *$args* | uninstall-package
}
```

Comment: @thewindowsnoob Maybe later.  Right now PS 7 doesn't support msi or programs providers.